# Virtual Click With jquery

Tags: jquery, click

I want to do with Jquery click function - I already tried google search but no result - I do not want the click button action. I want the Jquery Virtual Click action.

Comment: 'Virtual click action'? You mean like `$el.click()`?

Comment: Are you trying to simulate a click?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consult the [help] to see how to ask a question

Comment: @Jackhardcastle yes simulate a click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Virtual" click or other action be call [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$("#myButton").trigger("click");
```